# SSHJ and the Maven shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle, maven-shade-plugin, sshj

Testing SSHJ in Eclipse and everything looks good. But When I use the Maven shade plugin to package SSHJ I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:217)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPublickey(SSHClient.java:316)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPublickey(SSHClient.java:365)
at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPublickey(SSHClient.java:295)
at no.f12.SshRepository.executeTaskOnHost(SshRepository.java:23)
at no.f12.SshService.serviceCommand(SshService.java:22)
at no.f12.App.main(App.java:29)
```

Adding

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

changes the error message to:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Unable to reach a settlement: [] and [aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, arcfour256, arcfour128, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, aes128-cbc, 3des-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, arcfour, rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se]
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.firstMatch(Proposal.java:165)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.negotiate(Proposal.java:147)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.gotKexInit(KeyExchanger.java:239)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.handle(KeyExchanger.java:364)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:478)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:127)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:195)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:72)
```

Any idea how to get around this?

A bit of background to why I want to use shade... I am trying to get to a point where usage of Java and distribution of small utils is dead simple. So I create a really executable jar using this: https://github.com/brianm/really-executable-jars-maven-plugin . That enables me to create one, executable file to distribute and add to the path of the user. A bit like how Go has one binary file with all dependencies.

Comment: The code I'm using is available here BTW: https://github.com/anderssv/executable-ssh-util

Comment: To test working: `mvn -Passembly clean install && cd target && /bin/bash bin/app services stop`

Comment: To test failing: `mvn clean install && cd target && ./executable-ssh-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar services stop`

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. I finally gave up on trying to put everything in a big "uberjar".

Instead I assembled all the jars using maven-assembly-plugin, and then extract and add them to the classpath in order to execute, e.g. 'java -cp all-needed-libs/* com.company.MainClass'.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that might work is to add bouncycastle to the JRE extension library.

E.g put 'bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar' in folder '$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/' on the host.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign jar, it's required by Javax.security. I got similar problem and there's stacktrace from my test:

```
Cannot init Cipher factory: blowfish-cbc
java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:642)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:580)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.getCipher(SecurityUtils.java:96)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.cipher.BaseCipher.init(BaseCipher.java:88)
    ....
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: file:/test-jar-with-dependencies.jar has unsigned entries - library.properties
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:462)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:322)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:250)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:161)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:187)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:638)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:580)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.getCipher(SecurityUtils.java:96)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.cipher.BaseCipher.init(BaseCipher.java:88)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig.initCipherFactories(DefaultConfig.java:152)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig.<init>(DefaultConfig.java:107)
```